# How to know the date of adding specific layer to a map in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, arcgis-10.3

Is there a way of knowing when specific layer have been added to MXD file?
I work with MXD file with three layer with the same name: "polygon":

[image]

i searched in the source tab (in the layer properties), but i didn't found this sort of data.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I would expect you to be able to determine when a layer was added to a map is if it was added using code that recorded a time stamp for that action.

These time stamps could be recorded in a file geodatabase table, spreadsheet, etc, but not as part of the MXD unless you perhaps made the date added be a part of the layer name, which I would not recommend.